# How to update link table with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm learning about hibernate and i wanted to try and experiment with relations. ManyToMany in particular is rather troublesome for me. Hibernate generates db schema for me. It creates **movies** and **actors** entities properly, but it's not updating link table (**actors_movies**).
I'm using h2 database.

**Actor**

```
package Entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "actors")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "actor_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private UUID id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "year_of_birth")
    private int yearOfBirth;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "actors_movies",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id") }
    )
    //@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

**Movie**

```
package Entity;

        import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
        import lombok.Data;
        import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
        import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
        import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
        import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

        import javax.persistence.*;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "movie_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private UUID id;
    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private int yearOfRelease;
    @Column
    private int genre;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Main**

```
import Connection.HibernateUtil;
import Entity.Actor;
import Entity.Movie;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import java.util.List;

public class CinemaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Actor actor = new Actor();
        actor.setLastName("aktorrrr");
        actor.setYearOfBirth(8837);

        Movie movie1 = new Movie();
        Movie movie2 = new Movie();
        movie1.setTitle("jakisTytul");
        movie2.setTitle("ffggggggggggggggggfgfg");

        actor.setMovies(List.of(movie1, movie2));


        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(movie1);
            session.save(movie2);
            session.save(actor);

            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [bidirectional @ManyToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional) association you should make both sides in-sync.

So, I would suggest you to correct your mapping in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class Actor {
    // ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "actors_movies",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "actor_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id") }
    )
    private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
       movies.add( movie );
       movie.getActors().add( this );
    }

    public void removeMovie(Movie movie) {
        movies.remove( movie );
        movie.getActors().remove( this );
    }
}

@Entity
public class Movie {

    // ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and then you can do something like this:

```java
Actor actor = new Actor();
// ...

Movie movie1 = new Movie();
Movie movie2 = new Movie();
// ...

actor.addMovie(movie1);
actor.addMovie(movie2);


// ...
try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
   transaction = session.beginTransaction();

   // due to cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
   // movies will be saved as well
   session.save(actor);

   transaction.commit();
}
```

P.S.

1. For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`. That is why it's not recommended to use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` with `@ManyToMany` associations.
2. Look also at [this article](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/). This is not a good idea to use lombok `@Data` annotation with `@Entity`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation, i will try this as soon as possible. Also i heard something about lombok and jpa not working perfectly fine together but i didn't know what was that about. Now it is clearer for me, thank you very much.

Comment: I tried it and now i'm getting nullpointer exception. Debugger shows it happens while commiting transaction (line 35 in CinemaTest)

`org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
 at CinemaTest.main(CinemaTest.java:35)`

Comment: Try to use `session.persist(actor);` instead of `session.save(actor);`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I'm still getting a nullpointer :(

Comment: Could you please add full stack trace to your question

Comment: I had to use pastebin, stack trace was too long

Comment: It's difficult to say something from this stack trace. Could you share minimal project on github that reproduce this problem.

Comment: Sure thing: 

https://github.com/Karol011/HibernateSda/tree/karol

branch: karol

Comment: Try to use hibernate `5.4.29.Final` instead of `6.0.0.Alpha6`. Hibernate 6.0 is not stable and under active development now.

Comment: Wow, you are a god, thank you it works :)